# Operator not defined error?

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-update

I am trying to update a record but I get the error: Operator '=' is not defined for type 'Date' and type 'Integer'. How can I fix this?

```
    If Me.txt_Team.Tag = 0 Then
        sSQL = "INSERT INTO FixtureandResultsDatabase (Fixture_Date, Team, Ground, Score)"
        sSQL = sSQL & "  VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)"
        cmd.CommandText = sSQL
    Else
        sSQL = "UPDATE FixtureandResultsDatabase set Fixture_Date = @Fixture_Date, Team = @Team, Ground = @Ground, Score = @Score WHERE ID = @id"
        cmd.CommandText = sSQL
    End If

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fixture_Date", OleDbType.Date).Value = Me.dtp_Date.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Team", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Me.txt_Team.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Ground", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Me.cb_Ground.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Score", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Me.txt_Score.Text

    If Me.txt_Team.Tag <> 0 Then
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = Me.txt_Team.Tag
    End If
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    If Me.txt_Team.Tag = 0 Then
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        cmd.CommandText = "Select @@Identity"
        Me.txt_Team.Tag = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    End If
    MsgBox("Database has been updated.")
    conn.Close()
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error? This happens when you have an UPDATE or when you execute the INSERT?

Comment: It happens when I execute the INSERT.

Comment: What are the fields of the table FixtureandResultsDatabase? There are other fields that you don't touch with your insert ?

Comment: Yes, there is: ID, Fixture_Date, Team, Ground, Score, Result

Comment: what is the value of Me.dtp_Date.Text ?

Comment: @Juan it's a datatimepicker holding the date in the format 00/00/0000

Comment: I have tried with various combination of your INSERT query and a DateTime field in access. I can't reproduce this error message. Probably something about your database or your data. (I haven't asked but you checked the datatype of the field fixture_date right?) Can you give a real example of the data that you pass to your parameters?

Comment: @dave pls add a printescreen of the value of Me.dtp_Date.Text in debug mode, to ensure that is the correct value that you said.

Comment: Try to use  `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fixture_Date", OleDbType.Date).Value =Me.dtp_Date.Value.Date`

Comment: Here are some screenshots @Steve, the line you suggested didn't change anything [imgur](http://imgur.com/tXIYxdd,OsVIvZ1#0)

Comment: @juan screenshots in previous comment

Comment: Is that `cmd` a **global** OleDbCommand?. Do you have used it before reaching this code? (Really there is no need to keep around a global OleDbCommand, declare and initialize it when needed as local variable)

Comment: @Steve it is locally declared

Answer (score 0):

Fix it like this

Instead of

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fixture_Date", OleDbType.Date).Value = Me.dtp_Date.Text
```

Do

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fixture_Date", OleDbType.Date).Value = Me.dtp_Date.Value
```

You should post your table structure `[sp_help 'tableName']`. You obviously have date field but you trying to set `value` [object] to string - `Me.dtp_Date.Text`.

On another note - get rid OleDB ASAP - use `SqlClient`. oleDb will be decommissioned soon. Also, you can use `Output Inserted.Id` in your update and insert with `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`. It will return your identity all in one statement - instead of `Select @@Identity`.

Comment: If dtp_Date is a `DateTimePicker` there is no need to call `Convert.ToDateTime`, just use the value property of the dtp.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway - kind of missed that. for minute thought it is a textbox. Thanks

Comment: You may still be right.  I hope the OP is using good names.  dtp suggested a DateTimePicker to me.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway No, you're right. In the comments it says - this is DTP